# Paginaçao PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Criei uma pagina de busca com dois campos de busca, ela ta funcionando e tudo ok, so que quando eu pesquiso eu gostaria de paginar, e estou fazendo algo de errado.

Meu código.

```
<?php

  $conexao =mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$bank);
  $pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1 ;


  $consulta1 ="SELECT * FROM registro_clientes";
  $qrTotal  =mysqli_query($conexao,$consulta1) or die(mysqli_error());
  $numTotal =mysqli_num_rows($qrTotal);
  $quantidade = 2;
  $inicio = ($pagina - 1) * $quantidade;
  $totalPagina=ceil($numTotal/$quantidade);




   if(mysqli_connect_errno($conexao)){
       echo "erro conect hen";
       }else{

             {

               $nome = $_GET['buscar'];
               $bairro = $_GET['onde'];
           $consulta = "SELECT * FROM registro_clientes 
           WHERE nome_cliente LIKE '%$nome%' AND bairro LIKE '%$bairro%' 
           ORDER BY preferencial ASC 
           LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade ";
           $executar = mysqli_query($conexao,$consulta);

           $total = mysqli_num_rows($executar);

        echo  "Encontrado     ".$total. "     resultado(s):";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<hr>";                        

         while ($ln=mysqli_fetch_array($executar)){              
        echo "<br>";
        echo "" .$ln['nome_cliente'] ."<br>";
        echo "" .$ln['nome_comercio'] ."<br>";
        echo "" .$ln['tipo_com_serv'] ."<br>";
        echo "" .$ln['bairro'] ."<br>";
        echo "" .$ln['endereco'] ."<br>";
        echo "" .$ln['fone1'] ."<br>";
        echo "" .$ln['email'] ."<br>";
        echo "" .$ln['site'] ."<br>";
        echo"" .$ln['nome_imagem'] ."<br>";                     
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<hr>";                        
                    }                               
                }
          }  


       echo '<a href="?pagina=1">  primeira pag  </a> - ';

       for($i = 1; $i <= $totalPagina; $i++){

           if($i == $pagina)
            echo $i;
            else
            echo"<a href='resultados.php?pagina=$i'>". $i. "</a>";  

           }

       echo" - <a href=\"?pagina=$totalPagina\">  ultima pag  </a> ";





           ?>
```

Comment: Qual o erro que esta acontecendo?

Comment: deste jeito que se apresenta, ela faz a pesquisa e a paginacao,so que ainda apresenta todos os resultados levando as paginas seguintes, os resultados que nao me foram filtrados, basicamente ele joga todos os dados nas proximas paginas

Comment: explicando melhor, eu tenho 6 registro no banco de dados, pesquisando nos campos quero um registro, ele me filtra isso e joga o resultado, so que a paginacao ainda existe, se eu clicar na pagina 2 depois pagina 3 ou apertar o pagina 1 ele me joga todos os resultados que tem no meu banco de dados, eu nao to sabendo ou encontrando como fazer isso corretamente, que eu pesquise, e so me de paginacao caso haja necessidade.

Comment: @HenriqueOliveira, coloque sua explicação na sua pergunta por favor

Comment: Pelo resultado obtido me parece que o problema está nas variáveis, $_GET['buscar'] e $_GET['onde'], provavelmente quando clica na paginação as variáveis pegas por GET ficam em branco

Comment: entao, eu tinha uma linha acima delas assim       if(isset($_GET['buscar'])&& isset($_GET['onde']))      com essa linha a pesquisa funciona, mas a paginacao ainda persiste errada, eu vi agora que faltou essa linha no codigo que postei, to testando aqui muitas coisas em vão.